# Magento caching new file

Tags: php, magento, apc

I have created a php file and uploaded it to my Magento server but it's being cached. It's a standard .php file, but whenever I amend it, nothing changes. This has only just started happening.

Any ideas how I can stop this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your server hosts have installed [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) or another "opcode" cache.  I'd start with [clearing the APC cache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-clear-cache.php), and if that doesn't help then escalate to your server host's support system. Being able to deploy new code is a reasonable feature to want in a server.

Comment: We have our system set up using APC cache. If you have the rights, try doing a service php5-fpm restart (or whatever php you are using). Otherwise, try renaming the php file and accessing it, then naming it back. Sometimes you can trick the cache into doing a refresh.

Comment: Yeh when I rename the file, it does what it should, this is what made me realise there was some sort of caching involved. I'll get onto the hosts - thanks for your help!